# C# System.NullReferenceObject while reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

A System.NullReferenceObject exception is cast when I try to read the following XML:

```
<Settings>
  <Shortcuts>
    <Shortcut_1>CTRL+ALT+1</Shortcut_1>
    <Shortcut_2>CTRL+ALT+2</Shortcut_2>
    <Shortcut_3>CTRL+ALT+3</Shortcut_3>
    <Shortcut_4>CTRL+ALT+4</Shortcut_4>
    <Shortcut_5>CTRL+ALT+5</Shortcut_5>
    <Shortcut_6>CTRL+ALT+6</Shortcut_6>
    <Shortcut_7>CTRL+ALT+7</Shortcut_7>
    <Shortcut_8>CTRL+ALT+8</Shortcut_8>
    <Shortcut_9>CTRL+ALT+9</Shortcut_9>
    <Shortcut_10>CTRL+ALT+10</Shortcut_10>
  </Shortcuts>
  <Other>
    <Windows_start>true</Windows_start>
    <Report_bugs>false</Report_bugs>
  </Other>
</Settings>
```

Using the following code:

```
public static string Read(string read)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Settings.xml");

            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(read);
            //The line below causes the error.
            string contents = node.InnerText;

            return contents;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return "";
        }
    }
```

My intent is to read the Windows_start tag and the Report_bugs tag from the XML file using the above method.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: And what's the value of the `read` parameter when you get the error?

Comment: I added a comment regarding what line causes the error. I don't think it gets any value at all.

Comment: @SstrykerR what would you want your code to do when `read` is `null`, empty, or not an element in the xml?

Comment: I don't want it to do anything because it's not really supposed to be null. It's supposed to return a string containing either "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ditch the old code and use this instead:

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Settings.xml");
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            string contents = "";

            try
            {                    
                foreach (XmlNode node in root.SelectNodes(path))
                {                        
                    XmlNode child = node.SelectSingleNode(read);
                    if (child != null)
                    {                            
                        contents = child.InnerText;
                        return contents;
                    }

                    return contents;
                }

                return contents;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                return "";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless `read` looks like `".//Windows_start"` then `node` will be null, and therefore anything `null.method/property` will give `NullRefereceExceptions`